# DownloadManager - how to get information about Content-length header?

Tags: android, download

I need some help :).
I've got code like this:

```
    public void downloadFile(Uri uri, String title, String description, String subDir) {
    try {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setDescription(description).setTitle(title);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            //request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);               request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        }
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadDatabaseActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, subDir);

        this._bDatabaseMngr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        _bDatabaseMngrId = this._bDatabaseMngr.enqueue(request);
        /*** HERE IS MY QUESTION - BEGIN ***/
        Log.v(TAG, "File size (HTTP Content-length  header): " + HOW_TO_GET_CONTENT_LENGTH_HEADER_FROM_DOWNLOADMANAGER);
        if(HOW_TO_GET_CONTENT_LENGTH_HEADER_FROM_DOWNLOADMANAGER < getFreeSpace()) {
           // I'd like to handle it ;)
        }
        /*** HERE IS MY QUESTION - END ***/

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is Content-length value from HTTP header? Any ideas (min api level 16)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check DownloadManager status and error for your download id.

1. Set up broadcast receiver for
   `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`
2. Check status in `onReceive`

   DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();

   ```
   query.setFilterById(id);
   Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
   if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
       int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
       int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);    
       int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
       int reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason);
   ```

   }

All status codes you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE)

Comment: Yeah, I seen that before I ask my question.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that before I asked my question. I've got BroadcastReciver for object of my DownloadManager. But I need to check Content-Length before status will be failed. I know (I see in "Downloads" that DownloadManager knows how big is file which I'd like to download). I tried with  
                int error = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));   ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE but I'm not sure if I use it correctly:

Comment: if(error==DownloadManager.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE: " + getFreeSpace() + " REQUIRED: " + I_DONT_KNOW_CONTENT_LENGTH);
                    showDialogInsufficientSpace(getFreeSpace(), I_DONT_KNOW_CONTENT_LENGTH);
                }